# Context Switching or High runqueue , who is the culprit?

Tags: performance

I have an application which uses nio threads for which I have configured same  maxthreads and minspare threads ( tomcat ) . Now when the I hit with Load for a longer duration I observed sudden failures after some random time. Analyzing SAR reports shows that my runqueue and context switching has increased suddenly.

Also I have observed that even though I have configured X number of minspare and maxthreads , my application at its highest concurrency uses only 20-25% of threads ( 20-25% stays in runnable ) . Can this be a reason for high context switches and high runqueue.